# Casper require() with CoffeeScript not importing external files

Tags: coffeescript, require, casperjs

I followed [CasperJS's documentation](http://casperjs.readthedocs.org/en/latest/writing_modules.html) about including `.coffee` files from the main Casper test file. My code looks like this:

***home/tests/my_test_file.coffee:***

```
parameters = require('../parameters')

casper.test.begin "Test ", (test) ->

    home_page = parameters.root_path
    page_to_test = home_page + "my_page_to_test"

    casper.start page_to_test, ->
        test.assertEquals @getCurrentUrl(), page_to_test

    casper.run ->
        test.done()
```

***home/parameters.coffee:***

```
require = patchRequire global.require

root_path = "http://localhost:1080/"
my_page = "foo"
other_param = "bar"

exports = ->
    {
        'root_path': root_path,
        'my_page': my_page,
        'other_param': other_param
    }
```

However, Casper keeps telling me that `page_to_test` is undefined in `my_test_file.coffee`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's not a proper use of `exports`. First you don't need a function here, because you directly access the properties of the returned object. And second you cannot assign something directly to `exports`. That's what `module.exports` is for.

```
module.exports = {
    'root_path': root_path,
    'my_page': my_page,
    'other_param': other_param
}
```

or

```
exports.root_path = root_path
exports.my_page = my_page
exports.other_param = other_param
```

By assigning an object to `exports` (`exports = obj`), you overwrite the object that does the actual exporting and nothing is exported.